# How to have 2 domains on the same website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, multilingual

For a client we have setup a multilanguage website that consists of an English and Dutch part. The urls look like:

`www.example.com` for the english website and `www.example.com/nl/` for the dutch website

However, I want to change this `www.example.com`to `www.example.nl` instead of `www.example.com/nl/`

How to get this? We already have setup that both domains (example.com and example.nl) point to the same root. But we not yet able to have the /nl/ extension point to example.nl

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just define two virtual hosts with different DocumentRoot.
[Apache Core Features / DocumentRoot Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)

Comment: Could you provide me with an example? And will the website still work then? I mean, the core script is located at example.com/index.php , that rewrites stuff to example.com/nl/ ...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the /nl/ directory as root for your .nl Domain.

Answer (score -1):

I've not tried this, but I believe the [Move Homedirs to Different Webserver example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is a good fit for this problem. First, the example:

On the old webserver we just redirect all `/~user/anypath` URLs to
`http://newserver/~user/anypath`.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule   ^/~(.+)  http://newserver/~$1  [R,L]
```

And my thought on how this would work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/nl/(.+)  http://newserver.nl/1  [R,L]
```

Comment: I would never use RewriteEngine for this task.

Comment: @Roman: Oh? How would you recommend to not break existing published URLs?

Comment: @Roman: `FallbackResource` looks useful, but it cannot re-write `http://example.com/nl/Hallo/Neue/Welt` to `http://example.nl/Hallo/Neue/Welt`. The result is useless URLs in bookmarks, previous documentation, and search engines.

Comment: NL should be left intact, so it will work as before. Plus, you can use Alias. Many options. Personally, I don't use Rewrite Module at all.

Comment: But `.nl` is brand-new, and presumably they won't want to invalidate all the old content from `.com/nl/`. My approach will put the new URLs in the address bar for future correct use, allow old URLs to function with no annoyance to end users, and -- despite my misgivings about how the re-write module is abused -- this is simple to read and simple to maintain.

Comment: No, no, I meant .com/nl/ should still be resolvable while you add new hostname and edit URLs on the pages.